# Distance between the image of two vectors by the exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have a compact riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Take a point $p\in M$ and two vectors $y,z\in T_pM$ such that $|y|,|z|<\rho_{inj}(M)$. Recently I saw an argument saying that $d(\exp_{p}y,\exp_pz)\leq C|y-z|$. However I am not being able to come with a proof for this myself . Does anyone have any idea on how to prove this ?

All I thought of was that $d(\exp_py,\exp_pz)\leq d(\exp_py,p)+d(p,\exp_pz)\leq |y|+|z|$
.
Any help is appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Prove that for every Riemannian manifold and every point $p$, $\exp_p$ restricted to each $B(0,R)$ is $C(R)$-Lipschitz.